Bizarre behavior when I amend a commit
I hope someone can tell me what Git is doing to me.
First, a caution: the stuff in this repo is totally proprietary.
I doubt that I could sanitize it without changing it so much that the problem goes away.
Every time I push an amended commit to a particular branch, Git says, "Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind its remote counterpart.
If you want to integrate the remote changes, use git pull before pushing again."
This looks simple: someone else pushed changes to the repo since I last did. Except that no one but me has ever pushed changes to this branch of the repo.
I have confirmed this after getting the problem.
But I do a git pull and it tells me there's a merge conflict I have to resolve.
When I open the affected file I find my changes in the "head" part of the conflict (the first part) and the data that's in the remote repo in the "tip" (second) part.
I delete the "tip" part, save, enter "merge --continue," and push again. And it works, but the next time I try to amend the commit I go through the same routine again. Why is it doing this?

The commit that you are behind is the one that you pushed, and then amended locally. The remote still has the unamended version, and the server is saying "Hey, if you push, you're going to lose that unamended commit."

Anytime you amend a commit on your own branch that you already pushed, you must force push instead of a regular push. And you definitely don't want to pull like Git suggests, that will just try to merge your old one with your current one.

Side Note: if the reason this happens is because it's a shared branch and someone else pushed more commits, then you do want to pull. Also, this is going to be a dup (of many questions).

Could you comment on the reason you're amending commits? It could be that you're using the wrong tool for the job. Do note that amending a commit is exactly the same as dropping the previous commit and creating a new commit from scratch.

“This looks simple: someone else pushed changes to the repo since I last did.” Yes, amend-you did.

An answer that goes a bit more into details for a similar scenario and provides a safe forcepush alias that you definitely should use over a plain --force.

I'm sorry, none of this makes sense to me. I believe the explanation of what's happening, but I can't understand why. If Git finds a conflict between my current push and my own previous one, of course it should keep the change from the current push. How could it be otherwise? I think I should just dismiss this as one more bit of Git weirdness that can be avoided by using forcepush instead of push.

To answer the question, why I'm doing a commit --amend instead of a new commit: mainly to avoid having to enter the same commit message over and over. Usually it would be something like "Fixing various issues raised by reviewers." I'd have to work hard to write messages that were detailed enough to be unique for each commit, and what would be the point?

Another strong reason for amending a commit is that it preserves GitLab comments. Pushing a new commit sweeps them away, resolved or not. Yes, I know anyone can see those comments by displaying diffs for an earlier version, but no reviewer is going to that unless they know that unresolved comments are in it, and in my experience darned few will do it even if they know.
